# How to save stack of arrays to .csv when there is a mismatch between array dtype and format specifier?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, csv

These are my stacks of arrays, both with variables arranged columnwise.

```
final_a = np.stack((four, five, st, dist, ru), axis=-1)

final_b = np.stack((org, own, origin, init), axis=-1)
```

Example:

```
In: final_a 
Out: array([['9999', '10793', ' 1', '99', '2'],
       ['9999', '10799', ' 1', '99', '2'],
       ['9999', '10712', ' 1', '99', '2'],
       ..., 
       ['9999', '23960', '33', '99', '1'],
       ['9999', '82920', '33', '99', '2'],
       ['9999', '82920', '33', '99', '2']], 
      dtype='<U5')
```

But when I try to save either of them to a .csv file using this code:

```
np.savetxt("/Users/jaisaranc/Documents/ASI selected data - A.csv", final_a, delimiter=",")
```

It throws this error:

```
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('<U5') and format specifier ('%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e')
```

I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 1):

`savetxt` in Numpy allows you [specify a format](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) for how the array will be displayed when it's written to a file. The default format (`fmt='%.18e'`) can only format arrays containing only numeric elements. Your array contains strings (`dtype='<U5'` means the type is unicode with length 5) so it raises an error. In your case you should also include `fmt='%s'` as an argument to ensure the array elements in the output file are formatted as strings. For example:

```
np.savetxt("example.csv", final_a, delimeter=",", fmt="%s")
```